# Integrating lemmatization into Sphinx

Tags: mysql, sphinx, lemmatization

I have a MySQL database with a few hundred thousand text documents in it and I need to perform searches over these text files. I have decided to use Sphinx to implement search functionality. However I need users to be able to find all different forms of the search term. I have written a lemmatizer in python that is able to produce fairly accurate results, my question is: how to integrate it with Sphinx?
Help greatly appriciated.

EDIT: as there have been no answers yet, I would like to add that comments like "it is really difficult" or "it can't be done" will also be appriciated. If there's a problem with my idea, it would be good to know :)

Comment: I suspect the reason you have no replies, is nobody really knows what you are asking. lemmatization is a fairly specialized topic, and probably not that well understood. Maybe if you expanded teh question to include an example, to help visualize what you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but it's still here, so...

Sphinx now has [built-in support for lemmatizers and stemmers](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology).  The lemmatizer currently has [English, German, and Russian dictionaries](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/dicts/).  I'm not sure the format of the dictionaries, so I'm not sure how hard it would be to add additional languages (though the stemmers support several other languages).